# Parameterized Elliptic curve over Q with rank at least 1

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

Without explicit numbers, what tools are available to prove the rank of an Elliptic curve is at least 1?

To provide a concrete example to aid discussion, consider the curves:
$$ y^2 + y = x^3 - 18(k+1)$$
with the constraint on $k$ that $p = 72k + 71$ is a prime.

I have looked through many such curves for small $k$ (first 1000 meeting that constraint) and the rank (or analytic rank if Sage has trouble calculating the basis explicitly) is always odd.

How could we prove (or disprove) that this is true for all such $p$?

The above was chosen so that the discriminant has a known factorization:
$$\Delta = -2^4 3^3 p^2 $$
While not in  Weierstrass form, in case it is easier to approach with elementary techniques, note that the curve is birationally equivalent to:
$$y^2 = 4x^3 - p$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092734/determining-elliptic-curve-analytic-rank-even-odd

Comment: According to Sage, of the first 1000: 900 rank=1, 99 rank=3, 1 rank=5.

Comment: The simple way is to find a point that is not torsion and we know exactly how to find torsion points. In particular there are a maximum of 16 torsion points, so an easy way is to construct parameterized curves with at least 17 points. This is commonly done for construction of curves suitable for factorization via ECM. For general curves you can try to find a point and show that it has order > 16, but the problem is finding such a point (or show it does not exist). But of course there are more advanced techniques.